# Release build and debug build of a netbeans project

Tags: c++, build, wxwidgets

I compiled the wxwidgets using build=release now i need to know when compiling my project should i go for a "Debug" or a "Release " build and does it make any effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build of the wxWidgets libraries and of your project needs to be exactly the same.  So if you release build your application you must link with the release build of the libraries.  If you try to link an application and a library that have been built with different parameters then you will get linker errors and no executable will be created.

Most people keep two copies of the built libraries, one to link with debug applications and one to link with release applications.

Answer (score 0):

Nothig bad will happen, but debugging the whole project may be more difficult in debug build, because you will distribute product compiled in release mode and there is no effect.